# no puedo corregir caracteres raros al guardar en archivo .json desde python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de guardar un texto de python pero genera caracteres extraños " \u00f1 " y no sé cómo eliminar esto

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
with open("NoticiasHabboHotel.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(test_versions,   f, indent=0, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Este es el texto que me genera:

```
Dise\u00f1adores de salas, \u00a1os necesitamos!27345
```

Lo que quiero es convertirlo en letras normales.

He probado diferentes métodos, como encoding="utf8" y no funciona

Alguien podría ayudarme, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es que por defecto `json.dump(obj, fp, *, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True`
Si lees la documentación:

> If ensure_ascii is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If ensure_ascii is false, these characters will be output as-is.

Esto quiere decir que escribe los caracteres que no esten en la tabla ascci con su respectivo unicode y no hace el mapeo de caracteres. Luego cuando quieras guardarlo va a escribir el unicode tal cual.

Se puede ver por separado con el siguiente código:

```py
test_versions={"a":"diseñadores ¡los necesitamos! camión"}
g=""
with open("NoticiasHabboHotel.json", "w") as f:
    g=json.dumps(test_versions)
    print(f'ascii Default {g}')

    g=json.dumps(test_versions,ensure_ascii=True)
    print(f'ascii True {g}')

    g=json.dumps(test_versions,ensure_ascii=False)
    print(f'ascii False {g}')
```

Genera:

```
ascii Default {"a": "dise\u00f1adores \u00a1los necesitamos! cami\u00f3n"}
ascii True {"a": "dise\u00f1adores \u00a1los necesitamos! cami\u00f3n"}
ascii False {"a": "diseñadores ¡los necesitamos! camión"}
```

Solo falta poner el `encoding='utf-8` al guardar los datos:

```py
with open("NoticiasHabboHotel.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(test_versions,   f, indent=0, separators=(',', ': '),ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Esta todo bien, pero me genera ahora un bucle https://i.imgur.com/7IJixYD.gif